# How to use multipart/form-data uploading file using Volley

Tags: android, android-volley, android-json

One of my `API` use `multipart/form-data` to upload file and text in request body. How to code that like `Postman`?

Comment: Please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley

Comment: Follow this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56406730/how-to-upload-profile-pic-of-a-user-using-multipart-form-data/56439668#56439668

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a “multipart/form-data” POST in Android with Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16797468/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-post-in-android-with-volley)

Answer (score -1):

```
VolleyMultipartRequest multipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String resultResponse = new String(response.data);

    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
        error.printStackTrace();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("api_token", "gh659gjhvdyudo973823tt9gvjf7i6ric75r76");
        params.put("name", "Angga");
        return params;
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
        Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("imageName", new DataPart("file_image.jpg", AppHelper.getFileDataFromDrawable(getBaseContext(), mAvatarImage.getDrawable()), "image/jpeg"));
        return params;
    }
};

VolleySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(multipartRequest);
```

Comment: This code has zero instructions or context to it. For example where are you getting AppHelper from? Or VolleySingleton? If you just simply copy and paste this code it doesn't work, so that is why you should always explain and break down your answers.